# How to extends Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager

Tags: symfony, extends, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I want some changes in ModelMangaer then I was extending ModelManager but It's not working. I don't know why ?

Any one tell me why it is not working?

File where I extend Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager->

```
<?php

use Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager;


class ModelManager extends ModelManager
{

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getSortParameters(FieldDescriptionInterface $fieldDescription,            DatagridInterface $datagrid)
{
    $values = $datagrid->getValues();
    $values = $_GET['filter'];

    if ($fieldDescription->getName() == $values['_sort_by']) {

        if ($values['_sort_order'] == 'ASC') {
            $values['_sort_order'] = 'DESC';
        } else {
            $values['_sort_order'] = 'ASC';
        }
    } else {
        $values['_sort_order'] = 'ASC';
        $values['_sort_by']    = $fieldDescription->getName();
    }
    return array('filter' => $values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a very big problem here:

```
class ModelManager extends ModelManager
```

You try to extend class from self. It's wrong! You need to declare your base class with Fully Qualified Name or use `use` statement. Also you forgot to put namespace declaration. Something like this will work:

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Model;

use Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager as BaseClass;

class ModelManager extends BaseClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the namespace

```
namespace Acme\MyDoctrineORMAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager;
```

You need to use [bundle inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html).

```
// src/Acme/MyDoctrineORMAdminBundle/MyDoctrineORMAdminBundle.php

namespace Acme\MyDoctrineORMAdminBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class MyDoctrineORMAdminBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'DoctrineORMAdminBundle';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the service that is going to be injected, see:

[Admin's documentation - Reference - Advanced  (master) - 26.1. Service Configuration](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/advanced.html#service-configuration)

```
# app/config/config.yml
admins:
sonata_admin:
    sonata.order.admin.order:   # id of the admin service this setting is for
        model_manager:          # dependency name, from the table above
            sonata.order.admin.order.manager  # customised service id
```

For an individual Model Manager on an Admin Class please see this answer:
[SonataDoctrineORM - Model extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030787/sonatadoctrineorm-model-extends#15640967)